# Varbinary in SQL Server. What is the data type in Flutter(Dart)?

Tags: c#, flutter, dart, types

I have a column of type **varbinary(max)** storing images in my SQL Server database.

There is no problem on the C# side. I keep data in bytes.

What is the corresponding **data type in Dart?**

Database : SQL Server

Backend : C# Web API

Frontend : Flutter(Dart)

Comment: You can work with UInt8List, dart has no direct byte type(afaik), return integer list from your api, then use Image libraries to create image.

Comment: You are right when you say yes, but I am not able to pass json data from api to Uint8List.

Answer (score 0):

**Uint8List** is the **equivalent of a byte** list in the dart programming language. Thank you everyone.